# Uploading a windows volume to S3 Glacier Vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

So I am trying to upload my entire windows volume to S3 glacier and I am following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-glacier.html but this works in chunks. What if my volume is of 500GB? I want to automate this so that I don't have to upload in chunks. I see that tools like FastGlacier have this capability but it is not what I am looking for, I am looking for a CLI-based solution.

For reference, the subject volume is live on an EC2 instance and target is a vault in S3 glacier.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you wish to copy the volume to Glacier instead of using an Amazon EBS snapshot?

Comment: Hey John! Actually I have lots of EBS Snaps, I want to upload "those" to Glacier. One way is to attach them back as a volume and then upload those volumes. Right now I am doing this with S3 bucket as intermediate and then moving bucket contents to Glacier.

Comment: Let's step back a bit. What is the actual use-case you want to achieve? For example, what are you backing up (Windows volumes from Amazon EBS?) and how might you want to access the backups in future (restoring individual files, restoring whole volumes)? What do the volumes contain (application, data, database)? Is there any speed requirement for restoring data (RTO)? What is the frequency of the backup (RPO)? It's worth looking at the whole requirements before picking one particular tool.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than backing up your volume to Glacier, I'd recommend using an Amazon EBS Snapshot, or create an AMI. This works very nicely and is fast to restore.

Also, rather than using Glacier, I would recommend you store the data in Amazon S3 and choose a `Glacier` or `Glacier Deep Archive` storage class. This is much easier to manage.

Comment: Hey John! Actually I have lots of EBS Snaps, I want to upload "those" to Glacier. One way is to attach them back as a volume and then upload those volumes. Right now I am doing this with S3 bucket as intermediate and then moving bucket contents to Glacier.